# Opening documents in office

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

I am in the middle doing a test migration and making sure everything is in working order before the actual move.

I am having an issue with a powerpoint file not being opened in a web browser. From what I searched, I need to have Office Web App server installed? Is this the case or is there another way?

Currently on our SharePoint 2010 environment, it is calling this `_layouts/PowerPoint.aspx` to open the file in a browser.

Any tips or advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. If you need to open PowerPoint (or Word, Excel) file in browser, Office Web App is the only supported way for SharePoint 2013. Notice that you need to install OWA on separated server not on top of existing SharePoint servers.